# Resolve @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient with the token obtained outside of spring server of Spring Security 5.2.x

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a controller method that has an argument `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` with annotation `@RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient`.

```
ResponseEntity<String> getFoo(
            @RegisteredOAuth2AuthorizedClient("custom") OAuth2AuthorizedClient client) {
OAuth2AccessToken token = client.getAccessToken();
 ....
}
```

In order to resolve this, spring look for OAuth token on `OAuth2AuthorizedClientService` which actually stores the previously authenticated tokens in memory.

Now, I have a scenario where I obtain JWT token from OAuth server outside of this spring resource server, and trying to authenticate this server by passing token using `Authorization` header.

But when spring trying to resolve `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` it is looking for token in-memory with the principle of JWT (which will obviously not found since token is not obtained on this server). Hence send new login redirection for new token.

Overall question would be, is it possible to resolve   `OAuth2AuthorizedClient` with the JWT token (obtained ourside of the server) passed in `Authorization` header?